# electron include openssl in building.gyp

Tags: electron, electron-builder, webcrypto-api

I am trying to use node-webcrypto-ossl in electron which needs openssl libs and include folder to be included in binding.gyp.

I Tried including it in targets

```
targets": [
    {
        "include_dirs": [
            "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")",
            "<(openssl_dir)/include",
            "/path/to/homebrew/openssl/lib",
            "/path/to/homebrew/openssl/include"
        ],
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

In my .npmrc I just specify the OpenSSL directory:

```
runtime = electron 
target = 1.6.11 
target_arch = x64 
disturl = https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
openssl_dir = /usr/local/ssl
```

and I am able to build my electron application that uses node-webcrypto-ossl

Comment: is your .npmrc location in the user root? as in ~/.npmrc ?

Comment: `.npmrc` must be in near your package.json of electron application

Comment: I get ../src/rsa/rsa_oaep.cpp:35:48: error: ‘EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_oaep_md’ was not declared in this scope error when trying this. https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/node-webcrypto-ossl/issues/77 My platform is ubuntu.